# Buttons on the same row - Css/Html

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am tryin get all the buttons on the same line of height. Tried different min-height options for different classes but have no idea how to actually fix it. It's the red buttons under each product. Could you advise how I would go about fixing it?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Could it be the DIVs above the buttons pushing them down? If all the buttons are in a div you could try display: inline in the css. I can't see the code but i would recommend adding all the buttons into a container div which has display: flex; align-items: middle; etc

Comment: +1 on @Quentin, anyway you could try working with equalizing column height (either by javascript or by [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) ) and then positioning `absolute` and `bottom:0px` the buttons, with proper margins and horizontal alignment.

Answer (score -1):

```
ul.products li.product h3 {
font-size: 1.1em;
min-height: 53px;
```

}